# nginx https redirect from IP to IP (not to server name)

Tags: redirect, nginx, https

I am using a block to redirect all http traffic to https. Simple stuff. However, if I address the server directly by IP, it always redirects to the server_name given. If I do not give a server_name, it does not redirect. This is highly undesirable, as I may be on a LAN where a domain name would go unresolved. Here is my redirect block:

```
server {
    listen   80 default_server; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Use `$host` or `$http_host` instead of `$server_name`

Comment: Perfect. Y U NO answer?

Answer (score 2):

It redirects to server_name because you set it up like that. 
Look at your `return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;`. Either you replace `$server_name` by `$host` or by the IP you want to redirect to.